# Tactics for filtering out fake hotel reviews

Tags: hotels, tips-and-tricks, reviews

There is a popular question on how to spot fake reviews on TripAdvisor [How to spot fake reviews on TripAdvisor?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26840/how-to-spot-fake-reviews-on-tripadvisor) My question is if there are any tactics on how to leverage multiple review website to eliminate the noise or any other tools outside of the TripAdvisor itself. For example, I speak in three languages (Russian and Ukrainian) and read reviews in my native languages to check for reviews. My assumption is that hotel will not bother with hiring a company or an interpreter to boost their rating (you can exclude Spanish for Caribbean hotels as well). I also check multiple English websites hoping that if a hotel hired a company to boost their rating it will do it only for a couple of most popular websites. I apply this tactic only when I have a list of 5-6 hotels chosen based on price and TripAdvisor rating. I understand that assumption I make may be wrong, but after visiting two hotels with 4.5 TripAdvisor ratings that ruined my vacation, I would rather spend an extra hour or two to choose a proper hotel.

Comment: My view is that a few reviews are always fake, so if there are only a few than you know which they are!

Comment: Check the number of reviews a reviewer has posted. If a user has posted multiple reviews check the other reviews, should give you a good idea.

Comment: Of course, all answers would be equally helpful as tactics to better write fake reviews.

Comment: Personally, I don't go by overall rating, but I read the most negative reviews and try to decide if they give a poor rating because of something that would ruin my vacation (club in the basement, music can be heard inside the rooms) or something I don't care about (no breakfast available at the hotel). Then I go for a hotel that falls into the latter group,

Comment: The two answers so far do not attempt to answer your question and instead belong on your linked question.

Answer (score 4):

It is usually pretty easy to spot fake reviews. Those have some of these (if not all) symptoms :

- they include typos
- they are only positive or only negative, very rarely balanced
- they contain fake details (for instance "great pool" while there is no pool at the hotel)
- they usually don't refer to any specific employee that did a great job
- they look generic and don't offer added value insight (like "we had room XX and it has a great view over XX")
- if you look at the profile of the user that submitted the review, either it doesn't have many reviews, either all its reviews are too positive

Answer (score 2):

- you should not look for hotel reviews on TripAdvisor. You would better look for reviews on Booking.com, as they allow reviews only from people who has booked the hotel and lived there. The fake reviews will be very expensive as the property owner pays 20% of price to the Booking.com.
- do not read reviews from people, which are from the same country the hotel is located in.
- read bad reviews, not good ones. The bad always include issues in the hotel. If people tell it is noisy, in reality it is.
- pay attention to the rating. If the hotel has more than 20 reviews in Booking.com and rating more than 9.0, it is good. If the rating is lower, this means the hotel has some issues.
- the rating is not connected with price. I was staying in extremely cheap hotels with great comfort and in expensive ones with poor experience.
- read reviews in different languages. I have noticed that Russian people notice less issues in hotel, than people from USA.